# Object Detection on YOLOv7

Tags: python, object-detection, yolo

I am doing object detection on yolov7. I have trained the model with same dataset. However, when I train the model with 1 class it is giving the false object.[image: detection with one class]
However, when trained on the same dataset with 4 classes it can detect all the objects properly.[image]

How should I develop the model to detect each type of objects separately? And I was wondering if there is a way where I train the model with all the classes and when displaying the output image of the detection, it shows only the desired classes (one class only)?